# VBA code to show/hide pictograms

Tags: excel, vba, show, shapes

I have some code that depending on the value of a cell, it will display the correct health hazard pictogram.

It works if the result in D48 is 'AMBER-01' or 'GREEN' but it doesn't work for the others?

I've kept it as simple as I can but I can't work out why it isn't working?

```
Sub COSHH()

'If statements for visibility of Pictograms


If Sheets("COSHH").Range("D48").Value = "RED-01" Then

Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("GreenCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("AmberCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH")).Visible = msoTrue
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH2")).Visible = msoFalse


ElseIf Sheets("COSHH").Range("D48").Value = "AMBER-01" Then

Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("GreenCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("AmberCOSHH")).Visible = msoTrue
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH2")).Visible = msoFalse


ElseIf Sheets("COSHH").Range("D48").Value = "AMBER-02" Then

Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("GreenCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("AmberCOSHH")).Visible = msoTrue
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH2")).Visible = msoFalse


ElseIf Sheets("COSHH").Range("D48").Value = "GREEN" Then

Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("GreenCOSHH")).Visible = msoTrue
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("AmberCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH")).Visible = msoFalse
Sheets("Formulation").Shapes.Range(Array("RedCOSHH2")).Visible = msoFalse



End If

End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I've tried changing the last one to an else. I tried breaking each part into it's own IF statement.

No Joy!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no issue with your if statement set. With the code you provided I can't tell what exact information is being pulled and or what is happening within the arrays. However, a line within your if statement must be giving you an issue. Be sure to use message boxes and to use F8 to step through your code to get a better understanding of what is going on. See my test code below as it runs okay.

```
Sub test()

If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "RED-01" Then

Cells(2, "A") = "hi"

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "AMBER-01" Then

Cells(2, "A") = "hi2"

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "AMBER-02" Then

Cells(2, "A") = "hi3"

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "GREEN" Then

Cells(2, "A") = "hi4"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and keeping me sane.. the value in D48 is derived from a CONCATENATE formula.. there was a space before the RED01. I have adjusted accordingly!